# Android - Disposing of Listeners in an Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a few ListViews driven by custom Adapters (ArrayAdapter and CursorAdapter). In the getView() and bindView() functions of the adapters, I'm creating a row in the ListView and setting a Listener to a particular UI element in the row.

Currently, as the ListView rows are sent to the Recycler the listener is still hooked up so the memory is never released. I don't see a callback for when the row is being disposed of that would give me an opportunity to detach the listener before the row is recycled.

How do I manage the listener in the ListView rows? I only have the getView()/bindView() to add the listener to the row, but nothing to remove them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around I decided to use a ViewHolder pattern, and within that I have a variable that tracks the listener. When the recycled view is provided (where applicable) I pull out the listener (it *does* still exist) and make sure to unregister it as a listener, before creating a new listener and registering that in its place. This probably doesn't catch EVERY listener, but I'm OK with a few ListView rows being stuck in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Android OS does the `ListView` row view's recycling for you. The views get generated on the fly when user scrolls the list and get destroyed when they go out of view. Android OS destructs the views whenever other application require more memory and some of your objects are not being used, Sort of garbage collection.

And as to your question regarding removing `listeners`, they get removed automatically since the object they were point to doesn't exist anymore and they get marked as garbage objects too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The recycling is nice, but that's different from actually disposing of it. How would Android be able to dispose of the object when there is an external reference to it (the listener)? I mean, isn't that the definition of a memory leak?

Comment: Well, the trick here is that the system root has to have a pointer to it.

When you create a listener and attach it to a view, the only item with a pointer to the listener is the view. The application, through the activity, through the main view, through the recycle view, through the recycle adapter, through the layout, through the layout item, has a pointer to the listener. When the recycle view, recycle adapter, or the original view is removed the listener no longer has a connection to root - thereby it gets garbage collected.